# "The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded." Tried everything I can find, to no regard

Tags: 14.04, games, steam, mono

Alright, all I wanna do is play some games on Steam. I've looked at (nearly) every post about this issue and nothing has solved it so far. I'm also pretty new to Ubuntu, so there may be a ton that I'm not getting from the forums.

VERSION: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit

Here's the terminal output when I try to run Mushroom 11:

(Also yes I recognise the ELF class errors, as far as online help has told me, those are just regarding 64/32 bit and are bypassed. Other games work just fine with the same ELF class errors.)

```
    Game update: AppID 243160 "Mushroom 11", ProcID 12647, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/atlas/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/atlas/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/atlas/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/atlas/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/atlas/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Set current directory to /mnt/usb-TOSHIBA_External_USB_3.0_20140826006640F-0:0-part1/steamapps/steamapps/common/Mushroom 11
Found path: /mnt/usb-TOSHIBA_External_USB_3.0_20140826006640F-0:0-part1/steamapps/steamapps/common/Mushroom 11/Mushroom_11.x86_64
Mono path[0] = '/mnt/usb-TOSHIBA_External_USB_3.0_20140826006640F-0:0-part1/steamapps/steamapps/common/Mushroom 11/Mushroom_11_Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = '/mnt/usb-TOSHIBA_External_USB_3.0_20140826006640F-0:0-part1/steamapps/steamapps/common/Mushroom 11/Mushroom_11_Data/Mono'
Mono config path = '/mnt/usb-TOSHIBA_External_USB_3.0_20140826006640F-0:0-part1/steamapps/steamapps/common/Mushroom 11/Mushroom_11_Data/Mono/etc'
The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded.
It should have been installed in the `/mnt/usb-TOSHIBA_External_USB_3.0_20140826006640F-0:0-part1/steamapps/steamapps/common/Mushroom 11/Mushroom_11_Data/Managed/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll' directory.
Game removed: AppID 243160 "Mushroom 11", ProcID 12647 
No cached sticky mapping in ActivateActionSet.
```

I've tried everything from these forums, nothing is working:

[The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423682/the-assembly-mscorlib-dll-was-not-found-or-could-not-be-loaded)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490155/unable-to-run-net-app-with-mono-mscorlib-dll-not-found-version-mismatch

[Mono apps won't start because they can't load certain assemblies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13112/mono-apps-wont-start-because-they-cant-load-certain-assemblies)

I even tried changing the directory for mono:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452550/how-can-i-configure-mono-to-use-the-correct-paths-to-etc-directory-when-the-pre

I even dumped all the mono files to where it was requesting, after I tried that, I just get:

```
Game update: AppID 243160 "Mushroom 11", ProcID 12562, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/atlas/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/atlas/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/atlas/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/atlas/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/atlas/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Set current directory to /mnt/usb-TOSHIBA_External_USB_3.0_20140826006640F-0:0-part1/steamapps/steamapps/common/Mushroom 11
Found path: /mnt/usb-TOSHIBA_External_USB_3.0_20140826006640F-0:0-part1/steamapps/steamapps/common/Mushroom 11/Mushroom_11.x86_64
Mono path[0] = '/mnt/usb-TOSHIBA_External_USB_3.0_20140826006640F-0:0-part1/steamapps/steamapps/common/Mushroom 11/Mushroom_11_Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = '/mnt/usb-TOSHIBA_External_USB_3.0_20140826006640F-0:0-part1/steamapps/steamapps/common/Mushroom 11/Mushroom_11_Data/Mono'
Mono config path = '/mnt/usb-TOSHIBA_External_USB_3.0_20140826006640F-0:0-part1/steamapps/steamapps/common/Mushroom 11/Mushroom_11_Data/Mono/etc'
Aborted (core dumped)
Game removed: AppID 243160 "Mushroom 11", ProcID 12562
```

I love Ubuntu, but this is just so infuriating to try and work out.

Comment: You aren't using Wine, right? It doesn't seem so, but mscorlib.dll is a Windows library that, obviously, isn't available on Linux.

Comment: @Dugi , I have Wine installed, but I only use it for Windows-only programs (as it's used for). This is from the Linux version, and the game version is Linux as well.

Comment: Did you install steam from ubuntu repositories (with command `sudo apt-get install steam`) or did you download it from the site?

Comment: @ThanosApostolou , from the terminal ( `sudo apt-get install steam` )

Comment: @ThanosApostolou that worked for me, but I had to completely remove steam using synaptic